# Compiling hadoop java files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to compile Java Hadoop programs.

I have compiled and got .class files for mapper and reducer.

But when I compile mainjava file, i keep getting this error.

[image]
that is it can't point mapper and reducer class files.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: To copy text from the Windows command line: 1) Right click and select 'Mark'. 2) Drag or shift+arrow across the text to copy.  3) Press Enter.  4) The text will now be on the clip-board ready to paste.  --  Copy/paste the ***text*** of the error and include it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15267647/edit).

Comment: Have you set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH environment variable?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: No. How to set this?? And how to map my Mapper and reducer classes??

Comment: @AndrewThompson : I am using Putty.. And i can't copy.. :(

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure you'll need to for the compile. Are you sure that `hadoop-0.18.0-core.jar` contains the hadoop examples from `com.hadoop.examples`?

Comment: IIRC in putty you can just click and drag to select text, then right click on the selection to copy?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: Yeah i think it is having that. Coz i complied Maper and reducer using same command. The classes generated stored in /com/hadoop/examples/anagram in my tmp folder.

Comment: No when i right click it is not showing me custom menu to copy. Instead the selected text is passed as input when i r8 click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give all of your source files to javac

Example:

```
 javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar -sourcepath src/ -d build/ MyMain.java MyMapper.java MyReducer.java
```

Answer (score 0):

hadoop-core-${VERSION}.jar is in ${HADOOP_HOME}/share/common directory.

```
javac --classpath=${HADOOP_HOME}/share/common/hadoop-core-${HADOOP_VERSION}.jar YourClass.java
```

will do the work.