# How to run MapReduce for Multi Package Classes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, exe

I want to run my program in MapReduce by these conditions:

- Main Function exists in Package1,
- Class1 and Class2 exist in Package2,
- Class3 and Class4 exist in Package3.

I want to run the program under mapreduce. How can I run Main function, while I have 3 Packages?

Comment: import the classes that you need. start by looking at java basics before moving to mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

You can use any built tool like maven, ant etc. Or you can built it on your own using terminal but then be aware about the dependency of your class.

A jar file have multiple package and it will work in a similar fashion as single package jar works. When you will submit the job use

hadoop jar nameofjarfile nameofpackage.nameofclass(having main method) inputpath outputpath

Comment: Thanks , there are dependency between packages and classes. Is there any example for this . I use Terminal for producing Jar file .

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking out for examples you can just go through the links, as they tried to achieve the same thing.

[How to run a jar file in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012511/how-to-run-a-jar-file-in-hadoop)

[Compiling hadoop java files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267647/compiling-hadoop-java-files][1])

This should clear all the doubts.

Comment: try to avoid link-only answers, as they may become invalid once the links get broken. Instead, you can provide those links along with the core of the solution that they give.